# Filter array present inside a array of objects without affecting the main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I have JSON like below, I need to filter out workers having the age less than 25.

```
var employee = {
  "value": [
    {
      "position": "Seniro Developer",
      "description": "Developemwnt",
      "workers": [
        {
          "name": "Kumar",
          "age": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "aravinth",
          "age": 29
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 35
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": "Tester",
      "description": "testing",
      "workers": [
        {
          "name": "vinth",
          "age": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "rahul",
          "age": 45
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to use the below code, but it returns all the value inside the workers array, but my expectation is it should return only the employee having than 25.

If I use Map function it is affecting the employee Object also.

```
var filteredResult = employee.filter(e => e.workers.some(w => w.age < 25))
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "position": "Seniro Developer",
      "description": "Developemwnt",
      "workers": [
        {
          "name": "Kumar",
          "age": 22
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": "Tester",
      "description": "testing",
      "workers": [
        {
          "name": "vinth",
          "age": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a map and a filter, to avoid to modify the original array, you can use `Object.asign`

```js
var employee = {
  "value": [{
      "position": "Seniro Developer",
      "description": "Developemwnt",
      "workers": [{
          "name": "Kumar",
          "age": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "aravinth",
          "age": 29
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 35
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": "Tester",
      "description": "testing",
      "workers": [{
          "name": "vinth",
          "age": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "rahul",
          "age": 45
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



var filteredResult = employee.value.map(e => {
  let filter = e.workers.filter(w => w.age < 25)
  
  return Object.assign({}, e, {workers: filter})
})

console.log('original', employee)
console.log('result', filteredResult)
```

Comment: I have one doubt regarding this, Object.assign will create a new object and it is not the reference with the main Object correct? If yes, is there a way to create a reference from the main object instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and check if the filtered `workers` have some elements then push a new object with changed `workers` to the result set.

```js
var employee = { value: [{ position: "Seniro Developer", description: "Developemwnt", workers: [{ name: "Kumar", age: 22 }, { name: "aravinth", age: 29 }, { name: "sathish", age: 35 }] }, { position: "Tester", description: "testing", workers: [{ name: "vinth", age: 18 }, { name: "rahul", age: 45 }, { name: "sathish", age: 12 }] }] },
    value = employee.value.reduce((r, o) => {
        const workers = o.workers.filter(({ age }) => age < 25);
        if (workers.length) r.push({ ...o, workers });
        return r;
    }, []),
    result = { value };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```js
var employee = { "value": [ { "position": "Seniro Developer", "description": "Developemwnt", "workers": [ { "name": "Kumar", "age": 22 }, { "name": "aravinth", "age": 29 }, { "name": "sathish", "age": 35 } ] }, { "position": "Tester", "description": "testing", "workers": [ { "name": "vinth", "age": 18 }, { "name": "rahul", "age": 45 }, { "name": "sathish", "age": 12 } ] } ]}
result = employee.value.map(({workers, ...rest})=>({...rest, workers:[...workers.filter(k=>k.age<25)]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have one doubt regarding this, Object.assign will create a new object and it is not the reference with the main Object correct? If yes, is there a way to create a reference from the main object instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 0):

Use map and while creating the `workers` key in return object use `filter` to get employee with age less than 25. `map` will create an array

```js
var employee = {
  "value": [{
      "position": "Seniro Developer",
      "description": "Developemwnt",
      "workers": [{
          "name": "Kumar",
          "age": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "aravinth",
          "age": 29
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 35
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": "Tester",
      "description": "testing",
      "workers": [{
          "name": "vinth",
          "age": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "rahul",
          "age": 45
        },
        {
          "name": "sathish",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let filteredEmployee = employee.value.map((item) => {
  return {
    "position": item.position,
    "description": item.description,
    "workers": item.workers.filter(elem => elem.age < 25)
  }
});
let newObject = Object.assign({}, {
  value: filteredEmployee
});

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above given was a sample JSON I will have a lot of properties inside each object other than "position" and "description" so how to handle all those properties.

Comment: how they are different from position and description?

Comment: It is not different but I have more than 50 properties, I can't define each property like given above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method with [`...` rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
employee.value.map(({workers, ...rest}) => ({...rest, 
    workers: workers.filter(w => w.age < 25)}));
```

An example:

```js
let employee = {
    "value": [
      {
        "position": "Seniro Developer",
        "description": "Developemwnt",
        "workers": [
          {
            "name": "Kumar",
            "age": 22
          },
          {
            "name": "aravinth",
            "age": 29
          },
          {
            "name": "sathish",
            "age": 35
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": "Tester",
        "description": "testing",
        "workers": [
          {
            "name": "vinth",
            "age": 18
          },
          {
            "name": "rahul",
            "age": 45
          },
          {
            "name": "sathish",
            "age": 12
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  const result = employee.value.map(({workers, ...rest}) => ({...rest, workers: workers.filter(w => w.age < 25)}));
  console.log(result);
```